# Not getting CatalogEntryDataBeans using CategoryDataBean

Tags: websphere-commerce, usebean, jsp-fragments

I am using a UseBean in my Jsp

```
 <wcbase:useBean id="category" classname="com.ibm.commerce.catalog.beans.CategoryDataBean" scope="page" />
```

then I try to get 'CatalogEntryDataBeans' value using 'category' instance, something like

```
category.catalogEntryDataBeans
```

but i get nothing.

Please tell me what I am missing?

I have researched a lot , specifically set the targets (passed catalogId and categoryId to CategoryDataBean) but all in vain.

I have been trying to get catalogEntryDatBeans value for almost 7 hours, now no idea/debug-method left in my mind.

I would really be grateful if someone please help me get this value.

Answer (score 0):

Is the request properties object containing the categoryId and catalogId parameters?
Also, does this return a value: ${category.description.name}?

Are you getting the catalog entries returned in any other way? I.e. is your store, category and products correctly configured (including the description tables) and the issue is just with this data bean through this tag?

Comment: yes this ${category.description.name} returns value.Yes I got catalog Entries by using REST.

As I said, problem is just with category.catalogEntryDataBeans ... I am getting null when I use this.

Comment: Does this return values? ${category.subCategories}

Comment: Also, is ${category.catalogEntryDataBeans} really returning null? I expected that you'd at least get an empty CatalogEntryDataBean[]... To get null implies that an exception must be thrown during the method call. Have a look in your logs for CMN0409E (together with probably also "getCatalogEntryDataBeans").